# Why does gulp.watch or fs.watch not work on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, gulp, gulp-watch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, a gulp task like this;

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('./', function() {console.log('change!')});
});
```

or just calling `fs.watch` directly from node;

```
node -e "require('fs').watch('./')"
```

both fail with the following;

```
Error: watch ./ EPERM
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1429:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1456:11)
    at [eval]:1:15
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:77:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at bootstrap_node.js:315:29
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
```

How can I use `gulp.watch` under Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Bash on Ubuntu on Windows has no support for filesystem watchers like inotify.  You can vote for such a feature on [the project's uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13469097-support-for-filesystem-watchers-like-inotify).

Further discussion in this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/216)

EDIT: Looks like this has now been fixed in development and is set to be released to the general public sometime early 2017.

Comment: Has this build been released yet?